# varnish + nginx low throughput and hight response time

Tags: nginx, varnish, varnish-vcl

We have follow setup based on openshift

nginx => varnish (2 pods) => web api nodejs

I did 1000 request on one url in 60 seconds via jmetr.
This url should be cached by varnish and handle all requests quicly but a have follow result:

[image]

All requests have `X-Cache: HIT_1` from response header that means thay was handeled by varnish,

Looks like there is some queue or somthing else... not really understand so far

varnish conf:

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;
import bodyaccess;

backend freshproxy {
   .host = "fresh-proxy";
   .port = "3000";
}

sub vcl_recv {
  set req.backend_hint = freshproxy;
    if (req.method == "XCGFULLBAN") {
        ban("req.http.host ~ .*");
        return (synth(200, "Full cache cleared"));
    }

  if (req.method == "GET" && ! req.url ~ "varnish_no_cache") {
    if (req.url ~ "^/api/v1/tours/favorite" || req.url ~ "^/api/v1/products/favorite") {
        return (pass);
    }

    if (
      req.url ~ "^/api/v1/products" ||
      req.url ~ "^/api/v1/tours" ||
      req.url ~ "^/api/v1/farmers" ||
      req.url ~ "^/api/v1/stories" ||
      req.url ~ "^/api/v1/recipes" ||
      req.url ~ "^/api/v1/categories/farmers" ||
      req.url ~ "^/api/v1/categories/tours" ||
      req.url ~ "^/api/v1/categories/recipes"
    ) {
      return (hash);
    }
  }

  return (pass);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # We first set TTLs for most of the content we need to cache
    set beresp.ttl = 30m;
    set beresp.grace = 30m;
}

sub vcl_hash {
    # To cache POST and PUT requests
    if (req.http.X-Body-Len) {
    bodyaccess.hash_req_body();
    } else {
    hash_data("");
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_fetch {
    if (bereq.http.X-Body-Len) {
    set bereq.method = "POST";
    }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT_1";
    set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
    } else {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS_1";
    }
    set resp.http.X-Cache-Expires = resp.http.Expires;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Age;
    unset resp.http.X-Purge-URL;
    unset resp.http.X-Purge-Host;
    # Remove ban-lurker friendly custom headers when delivering to client.
    unset resp.http.X-Url;
    unset resp.http.X-Host;
    # Comment these for easier Drupal cache tag debugging in development.
    unset resp.http.X-Cache-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Cache-Contexts;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
}
```

nginx conf:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.my-app.ru;

        include well-known.conf;

        location /robots.txt { return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n"; }

        location / {
                    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name api.my-app.ru;

#        auth_basic "Restricted";
#        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/my-app.ru/my-app.ru.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/my-app.ru/my-app.ru.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
        ssl_stapling on;

        include gzip.conf;
        include location_deny.conf;
        fastcgi_param                   HTTPS on;
        # To allow POST on static pages
        error_page  405     =200 $uri;
        include well-known.conf;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/api.my-app.ru_access.log  main;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/api.my-app.ru_error.log;        


        location /robots.txt { return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n"; }

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_pass http://openshift-prod;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header realip $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
                proxy_set_header Ssl-Offloaded "https";
                proxy_set_header HTTPS "on";
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_read_timeout 1200;
                proxy_send_timeout 1200;
                proxy_connect_timeout 1200;

                ### SET GEOIP Variables ###
                proxy_set_header country $geoip_city_country_code;
                proxy_set_header region $geoip_region;
                proxy_set_header city $geoip_city;
                proxy_set_header postal $geoip_postal_code;

                proxy_set_header  X-City     $city;
                proxy_set_header  X-Country  $country;
                proxy_set_header  X-Region   $region;

                rewrite ^/pwa.html$ / permanent;
        }

        location /api {
                auth_basic off;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_pass http://openshift-prod;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_read_timeout 1200;
                proxy_send_timeout 1200;
                proxy_connect_timeout 1200;
        }

        location /img {
                auth_basic off;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_pass http://openshift-prod;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_read_timeout 1200;
                proxy_send_timeout 1200;
                proxy_connect_timeout 1200;
        }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend against layering varnish behind nginx. If you need TLS offload, use an option which does not parse HTTP such as [haproxy](https://www.haproxy.org/) in tcp mode or [hitch](https://hitch-tls.org/).
I suspect that you might be using jmeter incorrectly. Ensure that you have enough parallelism (threads) to saturate. I would also suspect to double check with [apachebench](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) using the `-k`option for keepalive and a high enough `-c` option (e.g. 1000). Check `ulimit -n`

Answer (score 1):

Through `varnishlog` we can inspect individual requests, their internal behavior within the Finite State Machine and their timing.

You can always run the following command:

```
sudo varnishlog -g request
```

That spits out extremely verbose content. It's all useful, but it might be overwhelming on a live system.

That's why I suggest using the following command:

```
sudo varnishlog -c -g request -i requrl -i vcl_call -i vcl_return -i timestamp
```

This command only lists the following fields:

- The request URL (`requrl`)
- The various states of the Finite State Machine (`vcl_call`)
- The transitions to the next FSM state (`vcl_return`)
- Timestamps at various points in the transaction flow (`timestamp`)

Here's some output of a **cache miss**:

```
*   << Request  >> 13290606
-   Timestamp      Start: 1637911747.472568 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1637911747.472568 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqURL         /
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1637911747.582202 0.109634 0.109634
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1637911747.582226 0.109658 0.000023
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1637911747.582427 0.109859 0.000201
```

This log transaction is for the homepage (`/`) and caused a cache miss. The total transaction time (represented by `Timestamp Resp` was `0.109859` seconds.

The reason why it took that amount of time is because the backend fetch (represented by `Timestamp Fetch`) took `0.109634` seconds.

Here's the output for a **cache hit**

```
*   << Request  >> 13290626
-   Timestamp      Start: 1637911786.334841 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1637911786.334841 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqURL         /
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       HIT
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1637911786.334933 0.000091 0.000091
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1637911786.334954 0.000113 0.000022
```

As you can see, there is no fetch because the object is stored in the cache. The `Timestamp Resp` marker tells use that the total response time within Varnish is `0.000113` seconds.

Once you figured out which endpoints are slow, we can include more information in the log transaction to figure out why it is slow.

Here's a `varnishlog` command that filters on a specific URL (in this case `/`) :

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"
```

> If you find a particular transaction that is too slow, add the full transaction to your question and I'll help you figure out why that is.

Comment: I understand that varnish's response depends on backend fetch time, but I did 1k exacly same requsets, As I see on back-end logs - My back recieved only 3 requests, reaminings requests was handeled by varnish I don't understand the reason of resonse time range from 300 to 5000ms

Comment: @Ilya Gather a couple of log transactions, paste them in your question and we'll figure it out together. Please make sure you add full transactions, because we'll need more than just the `Timestamp` field to figure out what's going on.

Please also add your `varnishd` runtime parameters to the question, so we know how you configured Varnish.